# JavaScript - How to make matching game cards stay flipped over after click

Tags: javascript

I found this matching game on codepen.io that I am using in corporation with a trivia spinner - thanks @Malky.kid - The idea is once they get to the matching game they have 10 clicks to match as many as they can but the cards MUST stay flipped over.

This is for a project and the odds of winning has to do with chance not skill.

```
(function(){

    var Memory = {

        init: function(cards){
            this.$game = $(".game");
            this.$modal = $(".modal");
            this.$overlay = $(".modal-overlay");
            this.$restartButton = $("button.restart");
            this.cardsArray = $.merge(cards, cards);
            this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray);
            this.setup();
        },

        shuffleCards: function(cardsArray){
            this.$cards = $(this.shuffle(this.cardsArray));
        },

        setup: function(){
            this.html = this.buildHTML();
            this.$game.html(this.html);
            this.$memoryCards = $(".card");
            this.binding();
            this.paused = false;
        this.guess = null;
        },

        binding: function(){
            this.$memoryCards.on("click", this.cardClicked);
            this.$restartButton.on("click", $.proxy(this.reset, this));
        },
        // kinda messy but hey
        cardClicked: function(){
            var _ = Memory;
            var $card = $(this);
            if(!_.paused && !$card.find(".inside").hasClass("matched") && !$card.find(".inside").hasClass("picked")){
                $card.find(".inside").addClass("picked");
                if(!_.guess){
                    _.guess = $(this).attr("data-id");
                } else if(_.guess == $(this).attr("data-id") && !$(this).hasClass("picked")){
                    $(".picked").addClass("matched");
                    _.guess = null;
                } else {
                    _.guess = null;
                    _.paused = true;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".picked").removeClass("picked");
                        Memory.paused = false;
                    }, 600);
                }
                if($(".matched").length == $(".card").length){
                    _.win();
                }
            }
        },

        win: function(){
            this.paused = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                Memory.showModal();
                Memory.$game.fadeOut();
            }, 1000);
        },

        showModal: function(){
            this.$overlay.show();
            this.$modal.fadeIn("slow");
        },

        hideModal: function(){
            this.$overlay.hide();
            this.$modal.hide();
        },

        reset: function(){
            this.hideModal();
            this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray);
            this.setup();
            this.$game.show("slow");
        },

        // Fisher--Yates Algorithm -- https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
        shuffle: function(array){
            var counter = array.length, temp, index;
        // While there are elements in the array
        while (counter > 0) {
            // Pick a random index
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
            // Decrease counter by 1
            counter--;
            // And swap the last element with it
            temp = array[counter];
            array[counter] = array[index];
            array[index] = temp;
            }
            return array;
        },

        buildHTML: function(){
            var frag = '';
            this.$cards.each(function(k, v){
                frag += '<div class="card" data-id="'+ v.id +'"><div class="inside">\
                <div class="front"><img src="'+ v.img +'"\
                alt="'+ v.name +'" /></div>\
                <div class="back"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/codepen-logo.png"\
                alt="Codepen" /></div></div>\
                </div>';
            });
            return frag;
        }
    };

    var cards = [
        {
            name: "php",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/php-logo_1.png",
            id: 1,
        },
        {
            name: "css3",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/css3-logo.png",
            id: 2
        },
        {
            name: "html5",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/html5-logo.png",
            id: 3
        },
        {
            name: "jquery",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/jquery-logo.png",
            id: 4
        }, 
        {
            name: "javascript",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/js-logo.png",
            id: 5
        },
        {
            name: "node",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/nodejs-logo.png",
            id: 6
        },
        {
            name: "photoshop",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/photoshop-logo.png",
            id: 7
        },
        {
            name: "python",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/python-logo.png",
            id: 8
        },
        {
            name: "rails",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/rails-logo.png",
            id: 9
        },
        {
            name: "sass",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/sass-logo.png",
            id: 10
        },
        {
            name: "sublime",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/sublime-logo.png",
            id: 11
        },
        {
            name: "wordpress",
            img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/wordpress-logo.png",
            id: 12
        },
    ];

    Memory.init(cards);


})();
```

see game [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awmyez/)

The only difference to this is that the cards stay flipped over - if they match cards they should still show that they are matched - it highlights green for a second. The cards flip back over after you select two cards ONLY if they do not match. If they do match they stay facing up but I need it always facing up. Thanks

Comment: Remove *$(".picked").removeClass("picked");*?

Comment: that did not work @Jonasw hmmmm